# What about zeros of higher dimensional power series?

Tags: nt.number-theory, power-series

Let $K$ be a p-adic field, $O$ be the ring of integers and let $m$ be its maximal ideal. Let $f(X)=(f_1(X),~f_2(X), \cdots, f_n(X)) \in O[[X]]^n,\ X=(x_1,~x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ is a  power series.

I am interested in the zeros of $f(X)$.

Now, $f(X)=0 \Leftrightarrow f_i(X)=0 , \ i=1,2,....,n.$

Now suppose I know **the zeros of all component power series** $f_i(X)=f_i(x_1,~x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ in $m$.

Does this constitute all zeros of $f(X)$ in $m$?

Isn't there matter of common zeros which are common to all $f_i(X)$ in $m$ ?

Suppose  I have $n_i$ zeros of each $f_i(X)$ in maximal ideal $m$,

i.e., $f_1(X)$ has $n_1$ zeros in $m$, $f_2(X)$ has $n_2$ zeros in $m$ and so on.

**Question:**

Is it enough information to know about roots of $f(X)$ from these information ?

How many roots of $f(X)$ are there in maximal ideal $m$ ?

**Edit:** I am considering only power series not formal power series.

Comment: In general, the notion of zero of a formal power series is meaningless.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, probably Masmath means to speak *only* of substituting $x$-values in $m$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, assuming they converge on the maximal ideal of p-adic field.

Comment: You have essentially answered your own question.  For $n = 1$, for example, $f_i(X) = (X - x_{i 1})\dotsb(X - x_{i n_i})$ satisfies your conditions no matter what $x_{i 1}, \dotsc, x_{i n_i}$ we choose, and the choices can be made so as to have as few or (within obvious sanity checks) as many common zeroes as desired.

Comment: @LSpice, for $n>1$, we have to select the common zeros of each component power series. Am I right ?

Comment: [Yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371272/what-about-zeros-of-higher-dimensional-power-series#comment938773_371272); there is no difference in this respect between $n = 1$ and $n > 1$.  This is just definitions.

Comment: @LSpice, You said no difference. But for $n=1$, we have just $f(X)=f_1(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n)$, hence all roots of $f_1$ are roots of $f$. But for $n \geq 2$, we are taking the common  roots of component power series. Isn't the difference? Can you please clear it ?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you were insisting that the number of polynomials be the same as the number of variables.  (So, maybe, did [you](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371272/what-about-zeros-of-higher-dimensional-power-series#comment938791_371272), since you wrote $f_1(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n)$ instead of $f_1(x_1)$?)  Yes, I agree that for $n > 1$ it is about common $0$s.

Comment: @LSpice, aah, I understand what you were saying. For $n=1$, you chosen $f(x_1)=(f_1(x_1),~f_2(x_2), \cdots, f_n(x_n)) \in O_K[[x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n]]^1$.. Am I right, you were considering this one ?  or Am I missing your above comment $f_i(X)=(X-x_{i1}) \cdots (X-x_{in})$ ?

Comment: I did not realise that you wanted the number of polynomials to be the same as the number of variables, so I was choosing $(f_1(x_1), \dotsc, f_m(x_1)) \in O[[x_1]]^m$ for arbitrary $m$.  (Note my $f_i$ have degree $n_i$, not necessarily $n$.)  Anyway, it doesn't much matter; the point is that you can manufacture polynomials with essentially arbitrary (and arbitrarily intersecting $0$ sets), so knowing the numbers of individual $0$s of several polynomials tells you essentially nothing about the number of their common $0$s (except crude upper bounds).

Comment: @LSpice, ok thanks. Little correction in your comment , it is not polynomial but power series

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If we can already find polynomials exhibiting arbitrarily complicated behaviour, then there's no hope to be able to say anything better for power series.